# SQL: I need to take two fields I get as a result of a SELECT COUNT statement and populate a temp table with them

Tags: sql

So I have a table which has a bunch of information and a bunch of records.  But there will be one field in particular I care about, in this case #BegAttField# where only a subset of records have it populated.  Many of them have the same value as one another as well.

What I need to do is get a count (minus 1) of all duplicates, then populate the first record in the bunch with that count value in a new field.  I have another field I call BegProd that will match #BegAttField# for each "first" record.

I'm just stuck as to how to make this happen.  I may have been on the right path, but who knows.  The SELECT statement gets me two fields and as many records as their are unique #BegAttField#'s.  But once I have them, I haven't been able to work with them.

Here's my whole set of code, trying to use a temporary table and SELECT INTO to try and populate it.  (Note: the fields with # around the names are variables for this 3rd party app)

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (AttCount int, BegProd varchar(255))

SELECT COUNT(d.[#BegAttField#])-1 AS AttCount, d.[#BegAttField#] AS BegProd 
INTO [#temp] FROM [Document] d 
WHERE d.[#BegAttField#] IS NOT NULL GROUP BY [#BegAttField#]

UPDATE [Document] d SET d.[#NumAttach#] = 
SELECT t.[AttCount] FROM [#temp] t INNER JOIN [Document] d1 
WHERE t.[BegProd] = d1.[#BegAttField#]

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Unfortunately I'm running this script through a 3rd party database application that uses SQL as its back-end.  So the errors I get are simply: "There is already an object named '#temp' in the database. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'. "

Comment: Sorry i didn't mention that i see 2 error. one that was #temp so rename and see what happen. also syntext error following. UPDATE [Document] d SET d.[#NumAttach#] =  
SELECT t.[AttCount] FROM [#temp] t INNER JOIN [Document] d1  
WHERE t.[BegProd] = d1.[#BegAttField#] 
replace Where to ON in above.

Comment: Thanks!  These seemed to help.  I still get an error "invalid syntax near d", unfortunately it doesn't tell me which one.  But I think I'll be able to figure it out.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Comment out the CREATE TABLE statement.  The SELECT INTO creates that #temp table.